# I have error loading data into PostgreSQL database

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.1, postgresql-9.3

follow up to the question, this is the command line i used but it could not recognize[command line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tX3iU.jpg) my password

[The Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/94Cbc.jpg)

I have a PostGreSQL script that contains table definition and sample data but whenever i tried to run the script, i get the error as shown in the diagram.

Please, does anyone has any idea o what is wrong?

I am new to PostgreSQL

Comment: Can you please post your query (or at least the first few lines) as text, rather than an image? Part of it is cut off in your screen shot.

Comment: It is quit a long script

Comment: ...Are you sure you're using the right password?  (If you're sure, psql is disagreeing with you right now.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the image, it looks as if you're using pgAdmin to load a database dump created with pg_dump. I'm not sure whether this will work with pgAdmin's query tool; you should try instead loading it from the command line:

```
psql -f the_dump_file.sql my_database
```

Full details here:

- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-pgdump.html
- https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/app-psql.html

Comment: Hi Ray, I tried to use the command you gave but the problem now is that it does not recognize the password for my computer username when i tried to load it from the file

Comment: The password is for the **PostgreSQL** user, not the computer user. You can specify the username to use with -U if it's different from the computer user.

Comment: Hi Ray, where can i do that?

Comment: Looks like you've done it already. :-) It's the green tick beside my answer. Thanks!